# Java: JButton Array and else if Beginner Issue

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, jbutton

Hey I got the assignment of identifying a code (not writte by myself). I chose a Java recreation of the game "Stacker" but I have some trouble finding out how some parts works.

The whole code can be found at [This site](http://pastebin.com/pqMMrDh7)

This part is the main issue and I would be greatful if someone would explain this in detail.

```
        public int check(){
            if (start == true){
                    return length[1];
            } else if (last<deltax[1]){
                    if (deltax[1]+length[1]-1 <= last+length[0]-1){
                            return length[1];
                    } else {
                            return length[1]-Math.abs((deltax[1]+length[1](last+length[0]));
                    }
            } else if (last>deltax[1]){
                    return length[1]-Math.abs(deltax[1]-last);
            } else {
                    return length[1];
            }
    }
```

Im a beginner if that helps

Comment: What don't you understand in this code?

Comment: Basically what it does in depth, I dont know what it is checking exactly and what it is returning.

Comment: Okay, I myself can't help you, since I'm not able to access your link at this moment. And I don't know what `start`, `length`, `deltax` and `last` is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the fact, that the whole code is such a mess, I'll explain it to you:

```
// checks, how long will be the next stack line and returns it (values from 0 to 5)
public int check() {
        // if this is the first line for the player
        if (start == true) {
                // return the size of the current stack
                // (in this case it is 5, because initialization of array length is {5, 5})
                return length[1];
        // if the horizontal index of the last stack is smaller than the horizontal index of the current stack
        } else if (last < deltax[1]) {
                // if the horizontal index of the current stack plus the current stack size is less or equal than the horizontal index of the last stack plus the last stack size
                if (deltax[1] + length[1] <= last + length[0]) {  // i removed the double -1, it's unnecessary
                        // return the size of the current stack
                        return length[1];
                } else {
                        // else return the congruent size of the current and the last stack
                        return length[1] - Math.abs((deltax[1] + length[1]) - (last + length[0]));
                }
        // if the horizontal index of the last stack is greater than the horizontal index of the current stack
        } else if (last > deltax[1]) {
                // return the congruent size of the current stack minus the difference between the current and the last horizontal index of the stack
                return length[1] - Math.abs(deltax[1] - last);
        // else the last stack will be directly under the currect stack
        } else {
                // so just return the size of the current stack
                return length[1];
        }
}
```

To improve "your" code:

- Avoid using static variables in your cases (use parameters and/or class variables instead).
- Don't use arrays like `length` and `deltax` if you're not using any functionality of arrays. You're only accessing them with `array[0]` and `array[1]`. So why not using for example `lengthLast`/`lengthCurrent` and `deltaxLast`/`deltaxCurrent`?
- Instead of `go`, `check`, `draw`, `back`, `forward` use better method names like `runNextFloor`, `getNextStackLength`, `drawPlayground`, `moveStackLeft`, `moveStackRight`.
- Instead of `if (condition == true)` use `if (condition)`

There is probably a lot more to improve, but hey: this is still **SO** not **CodeReview**!

Comment: Cheers, really appreciate the answer and I'll definately improve my future coding! :)